# Firebase .NET access

Tags: .net, firebase

If I want to use Firebase now from .NET in C#, what is your suggestion as the best way to handle the callbacks? I see your current client library is using WebSockets. Can you offer a small example of how best to set this up in C#?

Comment: did you get any sample?

Comment: use this lib. it works very well https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet

Answer (score 18):

Right now the only option is to interface with Firebase through the [REST api](http://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html).  This will not give you real-time data updates, but you can read and write to Firebase.  For instance, it would be very suitable for an ASP.Net backend to use the REST API to broadcast data to clients which are using the JavaScript client.

As for a full C# client equivalent to the JavaScript client (capable of syncing data and receiving realtime updates), that unfortunately isn't feasible right now.  The wire protocol used within the WebSocket isn't documented or stable, and the guts of the client code are actually pretty gnarly.  We're hoping to release a spec in the future so people can write more clients, but it's changing too frequently right now.  Sorry!

Comment: @Micheal, do you have plans for a C# client? Seems you just pushed out a Java/Android SDK. Any roadmap on .NET?

Comment: It's definitely on our roadmap, though no specific date set.  We have been getting a lot of demand though.  Follow us on twitter / our blog / our mailing list for updates. :-)

Comment: Hi @MichaelLehenbauer any news about this C# client ? Thanks !

Comment: @gabrielstuff No news, sorry!  It's still on our roadmap, but probably several months out.

Comment: @JeffO Still on the roadmap but no definite timeline.  Sorry. :-(

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer Same question, how about any news now? :D

Comment: @KumarRavi Sorry.  No update to publicly report yet.  We are getting closer to a .Net client, but there's a significant API refresh in progress that's delaying it.  Apologies.

Comment: you went google ... surely **now** is a good time to ask the same question again ? :)

Comment: @Noctis Haha. Fortunately, the Google acquisition isn't changing our platform agnostic strategy, so a C# client is still very much on our roadmap.  We know it's in high demand and we'll get it out as soon as we can.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer How about now? Any C# client coming soon? :)

Comment: Lets face it, Google simply hates Microsoft, today's release of C++ SDK proves it. @MichaelLehenbauer

Comment: And news on this? And will any C# client be either open source or ported to xamarin/mono/unity?

Comment: Hey guys is that the link sent by @TomášBezouška, has any one tested it yet its progress?, if so isn;t there any current blog showing a step by step example on this ?

Comment: Here's a blog post http://blog.bezysoftware.net/firebase-csharp-library/

Comment: Is their any stable version now ?

Comment: @Michael any news? It would be awesome to have an official C# library for FIrebase