# Real Time Collabarative editor API

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing an application in which I'd like to have near real time collaborative editing features for documents, similar to Google Documents style editing.

As I am new to this, I would just like to know of some APIs, if any, that exist.
I went through [JInfinote](https://github.com/sveith/jinfinote)
Are there any other APIs better than this?
Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking into Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/), here is an example of what are you are looking to do: http://www.firepad.io/ which is opensource.

Comment: I went through link. Its what exactly i need in functionality perspective. But it requires Node.js to be installed, which i am not using for my application. Anyways thanks for suggestion

Comment: Not sure what language you are using but there are clients for other languages than Node: PHP - https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php, Java - http://robert-reiz.com/2012/04/22/java-driver-for-firebase/, .NET is in the works - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729878/firebase-net-access

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look to [Mozilla TowTruck](https://towtruck.mozillalabs.com/) ([github page](https://github.com/mozilla/towtruck/wiki/Developers%3a-Getting-Started#head)).

It's an open source project, you may work on their base.
(or you may just use it and be happy)