# Using Websockets in place of REST streaming

Tags: nest-api

I'm working in C#, in a .NET CF 3.5 library that doesn't have proper support for processing REST streaming, at least until it's fixed.  Can I use a Websocket to connect for streaming updates?  I'm either doing it wrong or it won't work.  Thanks

Comment: Nest uses the Firebase API, so you will file the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729878/firebase-net-access

Comment: Thanks David.  Unfortunately I have a broken implementation in the tools I get to use, so I guess I'm kind of stuck until the libraries on my end are fixed.

Comment: hvolmer,
See my c# code for WebSockets in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962370/starting-rest-streaming-from-an-embedded-system

Comment: Thanks Kim.  I will see if I can translate that into something I can use with their custom WebSockets - which might well be broken also!