# Is there a Firebase .NET implementation with WebSockets?

Tags: .net, azure, websocket, firebase, signalr

Is there a WebSockets based implementation for Firebase (third-party or from Google) for C#.NET?

Almost four years ago, Michael Lehenbauer said:

> "The wire protocol used within the WebSocket isn't documented or stable, and the guts of the client code are actually pretty gnarly. We're hoping to release a spec in the future so people can write more clients, but it's changing too frequently right now." (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729948/4490069)

Today, the Web Sockets standards seem to be at a standstill and not, "changing quickly," the working group has had no activity, and the latest update to "The WebSocket API W3C Candidate Recommendation 20 September 2012" is October 2015 (https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/).

As Michael states, the demand was high enough a few years ago to keep this on the Firebase team's roadmap, but development hasn't occurred due to unstable standards.  The standards have become stable enough for Microsoft to develop a WebSockets implementation for Azure called SignalR. If nobody knows if Firebase is still pursuing an official .NET WebSockets implementation, has the community upgraded third-party Firebase support with WebSockets or HTTP keep-alive?

Comment: There is no official .NET SDK from Firebase. If it did, you'd find it on the Firebase web site, where you can already find the existing [3rd party libraries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/third-party.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that there has been an update via Google I/O, and an empty "Libraries" page on the 'new Firebase website' (from www.firebase.com), it appears the goal was to more tightly integrate with Google's Cloud platform, and not .NET.  So that promise likely died with the acquisition.