# using firebase in DevExtreme

Tags: c#, firebase, devextreme

I am going to use DevExtreme for the first time in C# in order to develop a single app to be used in all mobile platforms.

I also read about Firebase and found it so great to use.

After reading many articles and asking questions from the tech guys, its still unclear for me that are these two products working fine together specially after reading an article it seems that its not capable of syncing data and receiving realtime updates when using in c# :

[Firebase .NET access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729878/firebase-net-access)

I am also looking for a sample project that shows exactly how to use these two products at the same time.

Any recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aHIlVML0Hew

Comment: I'm studying the same thing. I have some problems, but I think I am in the right direction. Which tool are you using to develop the app? We use Phonegap (honestly, we use DevExtreme, based on PhoneGap)... if you use the same, I can give some hints to you