# Can we connect ASP.NET with firebase database

Tags: asp.net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is is possible to connect ASP.net with firebase database.
If yes please tell me how to do that

Comment: yes, you can always use REST API

Comment: Similar question is already been asked - here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729878/firebase-net-access